# Visual Studio 2022 - Files added to project requires reload of solution to be recognized

Tags: visual-studio

I am in the process of reorganising one of my solutions (its quite big) and whenever I move a file from one project to another, either drag/drop or copy/paste, the file appears in the project solution tree but for some reason Visual Studio does not seem to recognize this (as a  code file) and does not build it, or allow any intellisense or any "normal" developer things.

What I have to do is close the solution and then reopen it again.

The same situation occurs if I copy a file into the project folder in Windows Explorer. It shows up in the solution tree (with Show All Files enabled) and then when I "include in project", it does the same thing.

I've ensured that the "Detection" switch is enabled

[image]

Not a showstopper, but really annoying

Comment: What type of projects are these? C++, C# or otherwise?

Comment: The projects are all C#

Comment: Strange. Do you have any weird setting in the project file(s)?